# Why is this element null and why does it give me an input element?

Tags: javascript

```js
/*
Sections:
On the side there is sections, meaning, that you can make sections like, homework or just study

Smaller sections/headings:
These are big goals etc

Tasks:
These are tasks that can be completed and recorded
*/
function notifyMe() {
  // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
  }

  // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // If it's okay let's create a notification
    var notification = new Notification("Take a break!");
  }

  // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
  else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
    Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {
      // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
      if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
      }
    });
  }

  // At last, if the user has denied notifications, and you
  // want to be respectful there is no need to bother them any more.
}
notifyMe()
const sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebarTasks');
window.counter = 0;
const newHeading = (id) => {
  const sectionElement = document.getElementById(id);
  alert(id)
  sectionElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
const addSection = () => {
  window.counter++
  const newSection = document.createElement('input');
  newSection.setAttribute('placeholder', 'section');
  newSection.setAttribute('name', 'section');
  newSection.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  newSection.id = 'element' + window.counter;
  const test = 'element' + window.counter;
  sidebar.appendChild(newSection)
  const label = document.createElement('label');
  label.setAttribute('for', 'section');
  label.innerHTML = `<button onclick="newHeading(${test})">+</button>`;
  console.log(label.innerHTML);
  sidebar.appendChild(label)
  const br = document.createElement('br');
  sidebar.appendChild(br);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="sidebarTasks">
      <button onclick="addSection()">Add new section</button> <br>
    <input id="" name="section" type="text" placeholder="section"> <label for="section"><button id="">+</button></label> <br>
    <input id="" name="heading" type="text" placeholder="heading" style="position: relative; left: 2vw;"> <label for="heading" style="position: relative; left: 2vw;"><button id="" onclick="newTask(this.id)">+</button></label> <br>
    <input id="" name="task" type="text" placeholder="task" style="position: relative; left: 4vw;" style="position: relative; left: 2vw;"> <label for="task" style="position: relative; left: 4vw;"><button id="">></button></label> <br>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Pay attention to 102 to the end.
I get an error:

```
newHeading@/script.js:108:3
onclick@/:1:11

    at /script.js:108:3
```

And the alert gives me `HTML INPUT OBJECT`

I made a new variable that is just 'element' and the window.counter and I put that in the function parameter for my button but when the function is run and alerts the parameter, it says that it's a HTML Input Object

Also, the console.log(); shows `<button onclick="newHeading(element1)">+</button>`
So it does work but the function receives it as the actual input?

Is this because it automatically get's the elment using the id? maybe the name of the parameter?

Btw the comments are just planning.

SOLVED BY THE COMMENT BY @apple apple

NEW CODE:

```js
/*
Sections:
On the side there is sections, meaning, that you can make sections like, homework or just study

Smaller sections/headings:
These are big goals etc

Tasks:
These are tasks that can be completed and recorded

*/



//alert('test')


//Read localStorage:
/*
if (localStorage.getItem('object') === undefined) {
  localStorage.setItem('object', '')
} else {
  //let objectData = localStorage.getItem('object');
  let objectData = {
    section: {
      heading: {
        task: 'label'
      }
    },
    studyRoutine: {
      onweekdays: {
        mathBook: 'important'
      },
      onweekends: {
        mathBook: 'important',
        scienceBook: 'notimportant'
      }
    }
  }
  alert(objectData[1])
  // loop sections
  alert(objectData.length)
  for (var i = 0; i < objectData.length; i++) {
    // loop headings
    for (var y = 0; y < objectData[i].length; y++) {
      // loop tasks
      for (var x = 0; x < objectData[i][y].length; x++) {
        const myElementMade = document.createElement('input');
        myElementMade.setAttribute('type', 'text')

      }
    }
  }
}
*/
/*
objectData = {
  section {
    heading {
      task: 'label'
    }
  }
  studyRoutine {
    onweekdays {
      mathBook: 'important';
    }
    onweekends {
      mathBook: 'important',
      scienceBook: 'notimportant'
    }
  }
}
*/


function notifyMe() {
  // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
  }

  // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // If it's okay let's create a notification
    var notification = new Notification("Take a break!");
  }

  // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
  else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
    Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {
      // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
      if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
      }
    });
  }

  // At last, if the user has denied notifications, and you
  // want to be respectful there is no need to bother them any more.
}
notifyMe()
const sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebarTasks');
window.counter = 0;
window.counterHeadings = 0;
const newHeading = (id) => {
  const sectionElement = document.getElementById(id);
  window.counterHeadings++
  alert(id)
  const newHeading = document.createElement('input');
  newHeading.setAttribute('placeholder', 'heading');
  newHeading.setAttribute('name', 'heading');
  newHeading.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  newHeading.id = 'element' + window.counterHeadings;
  newHeading.style = "position: relative; left: 2vw;";
  const test = 'element' + window.counterHeadings;
  sectionElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<br>${newHeading}`);
  //sidebar.appendChild(newHeading)
  const label = document.createElement('label');
  label.setAttribute('for', 'heading');
  label.style = "position: relative; left: 2vw;";
  label.innerHTML = `<button onclick="newTask('heading${window.counterHeadings}')">+</button>`;
  console.log(label.innerHTML);
  sidebar.appendChild(label)
  const br = document.createElement('br');
  sidebar.appendChild(br);
}
const addSection = () => {
  window.counter++
  const newSection = document.createElement('input');
  newSection.setAttribute('placeholder', 'section');
  newSection.setAttribute('name', 'section');
  newSection.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  newSection.id = 'element' + window.counter;
  const test = 'element' + window.counter;
  sidebar.appendChild(newSection)
  const label = document.createElement('label');
  label.setAttribute('for', 'section');
  label.innerHTML = `<button onclick="newHeading('element${window.counter}')">+</button>`;
  console.log(label.innerHTML);
  sidebar.appendChild(label)
  const br = document.createElement('br');
  sidebar.appendChild(br);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="sidebarTasks">
      <button onclick="addSection()">Add new section</button> <br>
    <input id="" name="section" type="text" placeholder="section"> <label for="section"><button id="">+</button></label> <br>
    <input id="" name="heading" type="text" placeholder="heading" style="position: relative; left: 2vw;"> <label for="heading" style="position: relative; left: 2vw;"><button id="" onclick="newTask(this.id)">+</button></label> <br>
    <input id="" name="task" type="text" placeholder="task" style="position: relative; left: 4vw;" style="position: relative; left: 2vw;"> <label for="task" style="position: relative; left: 4vw;"><button id="">></button></label> <br>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need `<button onclick="newHeading('element1')">+</button>` not `<button onclick="newHeading(element1)">+</button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since `newHeading` accept `id` as `string` (which is passed to `getElementById`)

your

```
label.innerHTML = `<button onclick="newHeading(${test})">+</button>`;
```

should be

```
label.innerHTML = `<button onclick="newHeading('${test}')">+</button>`;
```

Comment: Thanks! Also I fixed it but how can I change it so my headings go in the section? i used the approach of appending it into the sidebar but if i have multiple sections it will just go on the end? how can I append it specifically under the section element?

Comment: @StudentUser1625 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: you can insert it at anywhere you wish :)

Comment: wait but it makes my add button go out

Comment: ``` sectionElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<br>${newHeading}`); ```

Comment: it just puts [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: OK you need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement for insert element.

Comment: should I try to put an ID on every label (with the button) so I can put it after the button?

Comment: If you have further question. it'd be better to ask a new question with proper title. So it can be easily searched.

Comment: @StudentUser1625

Comment: Yeah I just added an ID to every label